# Linking libwiringPi on Cross Compiler for RPI

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I have a RPI 3 model B, and I want to compile a small program for interacting with the device's SPI. I am writing the program on my Linux desktop so I want to cross compile the program. 
For this I have installed the cross compiler from here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools 
I am using witingPi library so I followed these instructions for installaion: http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/ 
The program I am writing is one of the examples from the web (just to make sure I can compile and run it):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <wiringPiSPI.h>

#define CHANNEL 1

void send3(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t c) {
  uint8_t buf[3];

  buf[0] = a;
  buf[1] = b;
  buf[2] = c;
  wiringPiSPIDataRW(CHANNEL, buf, 3);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (wiringPiSPISetup(CHANNEL, 4000000) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "SPI Setup failed: %s\n", strerror (errno));
    exit(errno);
  }

  printf("start\n");
  send3(0x40, 0x0A, 0x0B);
  send3(0x41, 0x0A, 0x00);
  send3(0x40, 0x00, 0xFF);
  send3(0x40, 0x0C, 0xFF);
  send3(0x40, 0x13, 0x00);
  send3(0x40, 0x01, 0x00);
  send3(0x40, 0x04, 0xFF);
  printf("done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the linkage part with the wiringPi library to work:
The compilation part works well:
`./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c /home/guy/main.c -o /home/guy/main.o -I /home/guy/toolchain/wiringPi/wiringPi` 
Where `/home/guy/toolchain/wiringPi/wiringPi` is the path to the wiringPi libraies and headers. I am sure this worked well since the compilation was successful (meaning the access to the wiringPi headers succeeded).

Next I have tried the following command to link the code with the wirinPi library and create the executable: 
`./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L/home/guy/toolchain/wiringPi/wiringPi -o "AngleCalculator"  /home/guy/main.o -lwiringPi`

This failed and I got the following message: `/home/guy/toolchain/wiringPi/wiringPi/libwiringPi.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized`

Some posts suggested using the `-static` flag during the linkage but it still didn't work and I got the following message: `/home/guy/toolchain/rpi2/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lwiringPi`. I guess this is because there is no static version of wiringPi.

Running the same linkage command on the RPI device itself works successfully.
I have no idea what causes this error. Is there another version of gcc cross compiler I should use? Maybe I should use another version of wiringPi?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I have found that this is my bad: 
When downloading the wiringPi library, I have built it with my desktop's toolchain. This created a so file that when trying to link it with the pi's toolchain caused an error. 
I have copied the so file from the pi to my desktop and everything worked fine.

Comment: Where exactly did you copy the .so file in the tools folder.